# SBS2003 add cals without MS activation

Tags: windows-sbs-2003, cals

ok I know this is a long shot but for reasons I wont bore you with we have a client who is still using an old SBS2003 and needs to add CALS to it.
They have valid 5 User CALS but Is there any way of activating the CALS now that Microsoft have closed down the activation server for 2003, or at least tricking the old SBS2003 to think they are activated?

Thanks!

Comment: The client _wants_ to add CALs. I'm not sure this is even possible anymore. Not to mention all the other risks of keeping 2003 around. The client _needs_ to upgrade to a supported Windows version.

Comment: Thanks Michael, its needed for an old btreive db app that wont run on anything above XP platform, its blocked from internet etc and locked down as much as poss but it cant be retired yet until the client replaces the db so until then i'm looking for a work around.

Comment: I wish you good luck. The client has had more than 10 years to deal with this. So far they've gotten away with ignoring it, but it looks like they have reached the end of that road.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to a supported operating system. Do not play games with activation. That enables an unpatched system to continue running, and is against the license agreement.

For help making it work, open a Microsoft support case. Their compatibility team likely has a shim or other mitigation to keep it running.